# RecyclerView's ViewHolders becoming unclickable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

**Prehisrory**

I have a list of stocks (some objects) from RoomDB. Each one of them have "symbol", "name",
"price" and what's most important, *"isFavourite"* fields.
I made a ViewPager2 with two Fragments containing RecyclerView *(actually there are just two instances of one class StocksFragment - one for all stocks, one for only favourite stocks)*. Each stock in RecyclerView is connected to the repository through Obsrver (data changes => stock's ViewHolder changes). Also each ViewHolder has own checkBox that changes "isFavourite" Stock field through StockListViewModel that calls StockRepository, that works directly with roomDB (with kotlin coroutines - sth like
`fun getStocks(): LiveData<List<Stock>> = runBlocking{ stockDao.getStocks() }`)

**Problem**

When i click the same checkBox several times in a relatively small amount of time, all RecyclerView's ViewHolders become unclickable (neither the delete button nor the checkbox works). *But i still can scroll RecyclerView* How can i fix that?
I think i am doing something very inefficient but i dont know what.

Here is my StocksFragment code:

```
package com.nikitakrapo.android.happystocks

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class StocksFragment(var stockListType: StockListType) : Fragment() {
    private val stockListViewModel: StockListViewModel by lazy{
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(StockListViewModel::class.java)
    }

    private lateinit var stocksRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var adapter: StocksAdapter? = StocksAdapter()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stocks, container, false)

        stocksRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        stocksRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        stocksRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        stocksRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        var stocks = if (stockListType == StockListType.favouriteStocksList)
                        stockListViewModel.favStockListLiveData
                        else stockListViewModel.stockListLiveData
        stocks.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
                { stocks ->
                    stocks?.let {
                        adapter?.setStocks(stocks)
                    }
                }
        )
    }

    private inner class StockHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        private lateinit var stock: Stock

        val symbolTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_symbol)
        private val nameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_name)
        private val priceTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_price)
        private val stockImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_image)
        val stockDeleteButton: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_delete)
        val favouriteCheckBox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.is_favourite)

        fun bind(stock: Stock, holder: StockHolder) {
            this.stock = stock
            symbolTextView.text = this.stock.symbol
            nameTextView.text = this.stock.name
            priceTextView.text = "$" + this.stock.priceUSD.toString()
            favouriteCheckBox.isChecked = this.stock.isFavourite
            holder.stockDeleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                stockListViewModel.deleteStock(stock)
            }
            holder.favouriteCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                stockListViewModel.updateFavourite(holder.symbolTextView.text.toString(), isChecked)
            }
        }
    }

    private inner class StocksAdapter
        : RecyclerView.Adapter<StockHolder>() {
        private var stockList: List<Stock> = emptyList()

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)
                : StockHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_stock, parent, false)
            return StockHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StockHolder, position: Int) {
            val stock = stockList[position]
            holder.bind(stock, holder)
        }

        public fun setStocks(stockList: List<Stock>){
            this.stockList = stockList
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = stockList.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try OnClickListener instead

```
holder.favouriteCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
    if ((it as CompoundButton).isChecked) {
        stockListViewModel.updateFavourite(holder.symbolTextView.text.toString(), (it as CompoundButton).isChecked)
    }
}
```

And provide stockListViewModel.updateFavourite code block. Is the problem reproduced when this line is commented out?

Comment: It worked. Thank You!! Is onCheckedChangeListener different from onClickListener? Isn't pressing a checkBox is the same as changing checkBox's state? btw updateFavourite deeply is sql query command:```@Query("UPDATE stock SET isFavourite = :isFavourite WHERE symbol = :symbol")
    fun updateFavourite(symbol: String, isFavourite: Boolean)```

Comment: It is a "monkey testing" issue, so it doesn't metter what is different between the listeners. Good way is to add a throttle for click events (e.g. RxJava.throttle functions).
More info about monkey testing: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner

Answer (score 0):

Calling `stockListViewModel.deleteStock(stock)` and                `stockListViewModel.updateFavourite(holder.symbolTextView.text.toString(), isChecked)` in background thread like
`withContext(Dispatchers.IO){stockListViewModel.deleteStock(stock)}` might resolve the issue.